# Аналог "функции"(переопределение класса-обертки) как аргумента Java в С++

Tags: java, c++, ооп, функции

Есть ли возможность воссоздать такой код **Java** в **C++**:

```
class Clazz {
  public void method(type arg) {
  }
}

interface Method {
  public void im(type arg);
}

public void run( Method m) {
  m.im(actualArg);
}

Clazz obj1 = new Clazz ();
Clazz obj2 = new Clazz ();

// передать obj1.method
run(new Method() {
   public void im(type arg) {
     obj1.method(arg);
  }
);

// передать obj2.method
run(new Method() {
   public void im(type arg) {
     obj2.method(arg);
  }
);
```

Всмысле, чтобы *функцию передавать как аргумент*, но ещё и *декларировать её прямо в аргументе*, без создания её отдельно и передачи ссылки на неё как аргумент.
Интересуюсь есть ли такая возможность в **С++**(в **Java** есть), если нету, то буду передавать функцию как ссылку. Или возможно есть лучшее решение?
Буду благодарен за советы и наставления.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы не о лямбда-выражениях?
Типа:

```
int doit(int x, int f(int))
{
    return f(x);
}


int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    cout << doit(5,[](int x){ return 2*x; }) << endl;
    cout << doit(2,[](int x){ return x*x; }) << endl;
}
```

Т.е. в `doit` передается не указатель на где-то определенную функцию, а сразу ее определение?

Comment: Спасибо большое, никогда не интересовался лямбда-выражениями, оказывается, что зря. Прочитал о них и это как раз то, что нужно.